# Import and convert JS files using Gulp & Babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Consider the following files:

```
//foo.js
(function(){
  console.log('working');
})();

//bar.js
import 'foo.js';
```

Now I'm using gulp to compiled from ES6 to ES5. Here's the relevant task:

```
gulp.task('build-js', function() {
  return gulp.src('bar.js')
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

My output file looks like this:

```
'use strict';
require('foo.js');
```

The isn't the outcome I expected. I want all code to import into the single output file using the ES5 conversion. This way, the single JS file can be loaded in a browser and run correctly. What do I need to do for the desired outcome?

Since `bar.js` only imports `foo.js`, the output file should look exactly like `foo.js`. Also, since `foo.js` contains only a self executing function, the output file should execute this immediately and log `working` to the console.

Comment: Is there any good reason you'd like to bundle it into one big file? With HTTP/2, this usually doesn't make all too much sense anymore. Also, creating one big bundle usually kills your browser's first-render time, causing unnecessary traffic.

Comment: @Chiru Will the `require` statement work in browsers then? I want to reduce the number of calls to the server and improve load times by serving a single minified JS file. It's worked well for me in the past. Otherwise I need to convert every file from ES6 to ES5 and create individual minified versions of each to serve in the browser.

Comment: Yes, it will. You can transform modules with babel and load them in your browser via a module loader (such as jspm/SystemJS). Serving one single minified JS file could likely not only harm your loading times, but also your build times (especially severely for big projects). As for the second thing you mentioned: Your gulpfile really is just one extra line away from that (`.pipe(uglify())`).

Comment: @Chiru Thanks for your input. I'm just wondering why would the load times be harmed by using a minified JS file? If the file size is smaller than unminified, surely it's quicker to load?

Comment: It's not the minification that harms load time; it's the bundle (that the client *could* download/parse/run in parallel) before **anything** can happen at all on your page. If only a part of the modules were necessary to start off your site, rendering could also start off earlier. Minifying that big bundle only harms build time.

Comment: @Chiru I see what you're saying. I'll look into alternative methods as you suggest. Thanks

Comment: Some buzzwords to google for: jspm, SystemJS, http/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a 'bundle' task if you want to create a single file for the browser. Take a look at browserify or webpack.

http://browserify.org/
https://webpack.github.io/

You usually need to specify an entry point, and the bundler resolves all the dependencies and creates a single js file.

EDIT:

An example task for gulp, using browserify:

```
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
gulp.task('bundle', function() {
    gulp.src('./dist/bar.js') // entry point
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});
```

Comment: Ah right! I thought Babel would do that job. I though `export`, `import and `require` were all ES6 features, so when converting to ES5 it would simply replace these with the relevant code...

Comment: It would be cool if one of you guys added the relevant code as an example to others visiting this question :)

Comment: Agreed. I already know how to solve this issue with webpack, but sometimes I don't want to mess with webpack and it would be nice to have the simplicity of es6 imports in my gulp build.